# Create split button gallery in RibbonX Editor

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx

I've created a custom Excel Add-In using the iRibbon Editor in combination with VBA to assign and program unique functions.I want to incorporate specific colors in the AddIn. So far I've been doing this with a gallery letting me choose the color. However, this is quite annoying as I mostly use 1-2 colors and I want to have them available in a splitbutton.
Is it possible to incorporate a splitbutton plus gallery with the Ribbon Designer?
I've seen a function called [SplitButtonGallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-controls-splitbuttongallery) but it doesn't work.

```
   <splitButton id="Splitbutton" size="normal">
      <button id="rev" label="Font" getImage="GetButtonImage" />
      <menu id="TJIO">
      <menuSeparator id="separathor" title = "Primary colors"/>
      <button id="gsdfhjkl" label="hgj"/>
      <menuSeparator id="sepkarator" title = "Secondary colors"/>
      <button id="gshjghjkldfhjkl"/>
      </menu>
     </splitButton>
```

If I include a gallery inside the menu, it acts as a second button to click in order to reach the colors.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) clearly states what controls can be children to all elements/controls.

> Is it possible to incorporate a splitbutton plus gallery with the Ribbon Designer?

No, it is not possible. The children of the split button control can be:

- a `button` or `toggleButton` (required, only one permitted, and must appear before the menu): The main button for the split button control.
- a `menu` (required, and only one permitted): The menu of a split button control.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)